# I am trying Time series forecasting using CNN , LSTM and MLP. But when i use TimeDistributed with CNN it gives dimensionality error, during fitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have 9 features, one output variable i.e. to be predicted, window size is 5
code works very well without "TimeDistributed" command

> MODEL INPUT SHAPE:    feature_tensor.shape=(1649, 5, 9) MODEL OUTPUT
> SHAPE:   y_train.shape=       (1649,)

```
Thats my Code:
    #Build the network model
    act_fn='relu'
    modelq = Sequential()
    modelq.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=105, kernel_size=2, activation=act_fn, input_shape=(None, feature_tensor.shape[1],feature_tensor.shape[2]))))
    modelq.add(TimeDistributed(AveragePooling1D(pool_size=1)))
    modelq.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
    modelq.add(LSTM(50))
    modelq.add(Dense(64, activation=act_fn))
    
    modelq.add(Dense(1))
    
    #Compile the model
    modelq.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error') 
    modelq.fit(feature_tensor, y_train ,batch_size=1, epochs=epoch_count)
```

THE ERROR STATEMENT IS :
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (5, 9)

I feel like there is some thing wrong with dimensionality of "feature_tensor" during "Model FITTING" i.e last command... But I don't know what's wrong with it :(

Comment: Can you share complete code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is right, the problem is the dimensionality of tensor_feature. If you take a look in the documentation of [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/time_distributed/) you see an example with images and Conv2d layers. There the the input has to have the following shape: batch_size, time steps, x_dim, y_dim, channels. Since you use time-series you need: batch_size, time steps, 1, features. E.g. you can reshape your data by numpy:

`feature_tensor = np.reshape(feature_tensor, (-1, 5, 1, 9))`

However, I am not sure if it useful to combine Conv1D with TimeDistributed, since in that case you apply the convolution only on the features and not on temporal contiguous values, where a 1d Convolution should be applied.